# Is there a workaround for QDMLOPNF 128 limit?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

iSeries QDMLOPNF API only returns 128 open files.   This limit is quite small for real world (meaning bad designed) applications.

Anyone has came up with a workaround?

TAATOOLS' CVTOPNF is based on QDMLOPNF as well

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think there's a limit of 128?

The API returns the following information:

- **Number of open files available**. The number of open files available to
  be returned.
- **Number of open files returned**. The number of complete
  open file entries that are returned.

If the amount of space you allocated for the API to use isn't enough to hold all the open files, the two values above will be different.

Per the [APIs by Example: List Open Files API, and the Display Job Open Files Command](http://iprodeveloper.com/rpg-programming/apis-example-list-open-files-api-and-display-job-open-files-command) article,

> Initially, I allocate enough storage to cater for approximately 400 open files. This would cover the storage requirement in most cases. Should it not suffice, however, I repeat the API call following a reallocation of storage based on the actual amount of open file information available.

Many of the IBM i APIs work in a similar manner.

The article contains some downloadable code that demonstrate the use of the API.

Comment: [Why do you think there's a limit of 128?] R = Because I misunderstood the example and did not proper research.  My mistake.  Thanks to your link and scriplet I could fix the program.   Appreciate your time a lot.  Thank you Charles.

Comment: I usually call such APIs twice. First with only enough allocation to get back info on how much is available (i.e., zero entries returned), and second with allocation based on the first returned values.